# Bx slider start after the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have a problem on my BXSLIDER. I want this to run after the page is loaded. I have used the ***onSliderLoad*** parameter but I don't know what to be added inside of this function.

Any help would be very appreciated. Here's my code below.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ){
    $( '.home-bxslider' ).bxSlider({
        auto: false, 
        speed: 2500, 
        onSliderLoad: function(){
            setTimeout( function(){ 
                 // this will allow to start the slider after the page is loaded.
            }, 100 ); 
        }
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys .. I already solve my problem. For those who are interested on this issue, try visit my demo below

[**`JSFIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/6j07bh25/)